# Variable not being updated and function duplicating

Tags: javascript, debugging

First of all thanks for any future help!

I am creating a notification script that modifies the title tab to make the (1) appear.
I am pulling the number of alerts from a notify_count variable updated by the website.

The situation I am facing is that:

1.The (1) appears in tab but is duplicated everytime the newUpdate interval executes.

ex: (1) my site, then (1) (1) my site, etc...

2. If notify_count value increases, the changeTitle function doesn't update numb and the same number appears in the tab.

ex: notify_count = 1 -> (1) my site -> notify_count = 2 -> (1) my site

```js
var numb = notify_count.toString();


function changeTitle() {
   
    var newTitle = '(' + numb + ') ' + document.title;
    document.title = newTitle; }

function newUpdate() {
   var update = setInterval(changeTitle, 2000);

}
```

Comment: You never increment `numb`

Comment: There's no need for the `numb` variable. Just write `var newTitle = '(' + notify_count + ') ' + document.title;`

Comment: Changing `notify_count` won't update `numb` automatically. You need to reassign it whenever it changes.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, how do I stop it from duplicating in tab though?

Comment: Thanks, are there no easier ways to code this? I don't quite understand your snippet.

Comment: You could save the original title in a variable at the beginning, and combine the count with that instead of `document.title`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the title already begins with `(notify_count)`. If it does, you have to replace that instead of adding the count again at the beginning.

```js
function changeTitle() {
  let prefix = `(${notify_count})`;
  if (document.title.match(/^\(\d+)\)/) {
      document.title = document.title.replace(/^\(\d+)\)/, prefix);
    } else {
      document.title = `${prefix} ${document.title}`;
    }
  }
}

function newUpdate() {
  var update = setInterval(changeTitle, 2000);
}
```

Another option is to save the original title in another variable when the page loads.

```js
let original_title = document.title;

function changeTitle() {
  document.title = `(${notify_count}) ${original_title}`;
}

function newUpdate() {
  var update = setInterval(changeTitle, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a duplicate title e.g.`(1) (1) my site`

because of this;

```
var newTitle = '(' + numb + ') ' + document.title;
document.title = newTitle;
```

You are setting `document.title` to `newTitle`'s value but you are using the existing `document.title` value in defining `newTitle`. In essence this line is appending "(num)" to the `document.title` again and again and again.

The first time through `document.title` is "My Site" before you append the "(num)".  Then the next time through `document.title` is "(1) My Site", which is then used to define `newTitle` to be "(1) (1) My Site".  etc...

To correct this you can use a RegEx in `changeTitle()` to replace only the "(num)" portion of the document.title with [String.Replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or you can define a new var at the top to hold the original `document.title` and use that var as the base from which to build your `newTitle`